# React: why doesn't React.addons.cloneWithProps work with Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know if this is a bug or how to work this around, but I've noticed that React.addons.cloneWithProps works with standard tags (like `<div>`) but not with children that are components.

This is a working example of the problem. I expect both the divs to have a red background, but the one created with a component does not.

http://jsfiddle.net/ydpk2dp7/1/

```
var Main = React.createClass({
    render: function() {     
       children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function (c, index) {
            return React.addons.cloneWithProps(c, {
                style: {
                    background: 'red'
                }
            });
       });

       return (
           <div>
               {children}
           </div>
       );
    },    
});

var Comp = React.createClass({
    render: function() {     
          return (
              <div>{this.props.children}</div>
          ); 
    }
});


React.render(
    <Main>
        <div>1</div>
        <Comp>2</Comp>
    </Main>
    , document.body);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not but I would wrap the react components in a parent not owned by the parent component.  The below provides a working result.

```
var Main = React.createClass({
    render: function() {     
       children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function (c, index) {
            return React.addons.cloneWithProps(c, {style: {background: 'red'}});
       });

       return (
           <div>
               {children}
           </div>
       );
    },    
});

var Comp = React.createClass({
    render: function() {     
          return (
              <div>{this.props.children}</div>
          ); 
    }
});


React.render(
    <Main>
        <div>
            <Comp>2</Comp>
            <Comp>3</Comp>
            <Comp>4</Comp>
        </div>
    </Main>
    , document.body)
```

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but thought I'd help whoever sees this in the future.

The problem is you're discarding the `style` prop in `Comp`:

```
var Comp = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
          var style = this.props.style; // you weren't passing this to the <div> below
          return (
              <div style={style}>{this.props.children}</div>
          );
    }
});
```

It's probably best to extract what you need from `props` and pass on the rest. Easily done with ES2015's [destructuring spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
var Comp = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
          var { children, ...props } = this.props;
          return (
              <div {...props}>{ children }</div>
          );
    }
});
```

This will allow props to be specified on your component that, when initially writing, you didn't think of.

Now, for example, you can now add an `onClick` handler and expect it to work:

```
<Comp onClick={this.onClick} />
```

**Remember**, only `props` on "DOM" elements have special meaning. To custom elements, they're just regular properties for you to interpret as you wish.